# Counterexample for applying directed graph's max-flow algorithm on undirected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm looking for examples of very simple graphs (preferably less than 10 nodes) that would serve as counterexamples to the claim that the Edmonds-Karp's algorithm would work on undirected graphs out-of-the-box.

I know you can modify the graph and the algorithm to make it work. What I'm looking for is an example to convince immediately that this effort is necessary.